# Gluing pvc quarter round in the shower corner

Tags: shower, tile, pvc

I had my shower done and the tile work is very ugly in corners.
Wondering if gluing PVC finished quarter round with clear silicone would work in the long run?
Anyone had any experience with it? Any suggestions?

[image: quorter round]

Comment: Have you considered actual tile cove or bead? Might look more polished and hold up better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the "ugliness" is wide enough that a good bead of white caulk, which you'd expect in a shower corner, won't solve the problem. in that case, this will work fine and is something I've done before. One suggestion would be to use some  dabs of fast drying epoxy to secure it in place and then clear silicone caulk both sides of the corner trim, and the top and bottom. The reason for this is if you just use caulk you'll be holding the corner in place until the caulk hardens to prevent the corner from separating from the wall..... that will take a while. You might be able to tape it in place temporarily but that sometimes doesn't work. Good luck.

Comment: I like the epoxy or possibly a few dabs of construction adhesive to hold the 1/4 round in place then the calking.

Comment: I agree. Panel adhesive sets more quickly than regular construction adhesive. Be sure to not let it squeeze out and make a brown mess. A few dabs right in the corner should do. The beads of caulk along the sides will ultimately provide the holding power.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid pure silicone. Not only is it harder to work with, it's a nightmare to scrape and replace (and you **will** have to replace it eventually).

Instead, use a high-grade adhesive that **works with vinyl/PVC** (a surprising amount do not). [DAP makes one](https://www.dap.com/dap-products-ph/dynagrip-heavy-duty-max-construction-adhesive/), but there are others on the market as well.